# Prove that infimum of probability measure is zero

Tags: probability, measure-theory

given probability space, let A be algebra of subsets of event space F. Prove that $$\forall C\in\sigma(A)$$ it is true that $$\inf_{B\in A}{P(C\triangle B)} = 0$$

I guess the only way to do it is to prove by contradiction, but I can't come up with something after writing it. Pls give me a hint to solve the task, any help would be great

Comment: I suggest explaining what routes you have considered, just for reassurance that you've given this a go.

Comment: This is the standard approximation theorem of measure theory. Halmos' book has a proof.